# mlr: Tune model parameters with validation set

Tags: r, hyperparameters, mlr

Just switched to [mlr](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/) for my machine learning workflow. I am wondering if it is possible to tune hyperparameters using a separate validation set. From my minimum understanding, `makeResampleDesc` and `makeResampleInstance` accepts only resampling from training data.

My goal is to tune parameters with a validation set and test the final model with the test set. This is to prevent overfitting and knowledge leak.

Here is what I did code-wise:

```
## Create training, validation and test tasks
train_task <- makeClassifTask(data = train_data, target = "y", positive = 1)
validation_task <- makeClassifTask(data = validation_data, target = "y")
test_task <- makeClassifTask(data = test_data, target = "y")

## Attempt to tune parameters with separate validation data
tuned_params <- tuneParams(
    task = train_task,
    resampling = makeResampleInstance("Holdout", task = validation_task),
    ...
)
```

From the error message, it looks like evaluation is still trying to resample from the training set:

> 00001: Error in resample.fun(learner2, task, resampling, measures =
>   measures,  :    Size of data set: 19454 and resampling instance:
>   1666333 differ!

Does anyone know what I should do? Am I setting up everything the right way?

Comment: You don't need to split the data into separate tasks, you can use just one and [nested resampling](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/nested_resampling.html). In particular, you would have a holdout resampling for the outer and whatever else you want for the inner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update as of 2019/03/27]**

Following @jakob-r's comment, and finally understanding @LarsKotthoff's suggestion, here is what I did:

```
## Create combined training data
train_task_data <- rbind(train_data, validation_data)

## Create learner, training task, etc.
xgb_learner <- makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
train_task <- makeClassifTask(data = train_task_data, target = "y", positive = 1)

## Tune hyperparameters
tune_wrapper <- makeTuneWrapper(
  learner = xgb_learner,
  resampling = makeResampleDesc("Holdout"),
  measures = ...,
  par.set = ...,
  control = ...
)
model_xgb <- train(tune_wrapper, train_task)
```

---

Here is what I did following @LarsKotthoff 's comment. Assume you have two separate datasets for training (`train_data`) and validation (`validation_data`):

```
## Create combined training data
train_task_data <- rbind(train_data, validation_data)
size <- nrow(train_task_data)
train_ind <- seq_len(nrow(train_data))
validation_ind <- seq.int(max(train_ind) + 1, size)

## Create training task
train_task <- makeClassifTask(data = train_task_data, target = "y", positive = 1)

## Tune hyperparameters
tuned_params <- tuneParams(
    task = train_task,
    resampling = makeFixedHoldoutInstance(train_ind, validation_ind, size),
    ...
)
```

After optimizing the hyperparameter set, you can build a final model and test against your test dataset.

**Note**: I have to install the latest development version (as of 2018/08/06) from GitHub. Current CRAN version (2.12.1) throws an error when I call `makeFixedHoldoutInstance()`, i.e.,

> Assertion on 'discrete.names' failed: Must be of type 'logical flag',
>   not 'NULL'.

Comment: But @Lars pointed you to the nested resampling page where it directly tells you to use `makeTuneWrapper()` on the learner. Afterwards you don't call `tuneParams()` manually anymore.